# Expected count of event based on different probabilities per independent day

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

This is very basic, but I just want certainty that what I'm doing isn't stupid.

Say I have a set of data which gives me a probability of an event A happening each day for a week.

For example:

```
day 1: 0.1
day 2: 0.15
day 3: 0.05
day 4: 0.1
day 5: 0.1
day 6: 0.05
day 7: 0.05
```

Now, what I want is the number of event A we expect to have happened after these 7 days.

What I would do, considering this binomial distribution, is:

```
E = 0.1 + 0.15 + 0.05 + 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.05 + 0.05 = 0.6
```

Hence, we expect 0.6 event A to happen during that week.

Is this correct?

As an aside, I'll then want to apply a Poisson process on this to obtain the probability of the event A happening within the next year, that is P(t < 1y) = 1 - exp(-**0.6**/7 * 365)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right. 
The expected value of A event in a week is:
$$ E[X] = 1 \cdot 0.1 + 1 \cdot 0.15 + 1 \cdot 0.05 + 1 \cdot 0.1 + 1 \cdot 0.1 +1 \cdot 0.05 + 1 \cdot 0.05 = 0.6 $$

And when k is the number of A events happen, the Poisson distirbution probability is:
$$ p( k ; \lambda) = e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^k}{k!} $$
$$ \text{where } \lambda = \frac{events}{time}*period$$

Then, the probability of the event A happening in next 365/7 weeks is equal to 1 minus the probability of the event A not happening at all:
$$ 1- P(k=0; \lambda) = 1 - e^{-0.6 * 365/7} \frac{\lambda^0}{0!} $$

which is almost 1.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, so, I decided to test it out in python:

```
import numpy as np
rows = [(1, 0.1), (2, 0.15), (3, 0.05), (4, 0.1), (5, 0.1), (6, 0.05), (7, 0.05)]

scenario = 0
n=50000
elts, probs = np.array(rows).T
m = len(elts)
scenario = [elts[np.random.rand(m) < probs].astype(int) for _ in range(n)]

print(np.mean([len(i) for i in scenario]))
```

This gives me when I run it 10 times:

```
0.60118
0.59308
0.60536
0.59812
0.6013
0.59246
0.6025
0.6027
0.60146
0.59656
0.59716
```

Hence it should confirm empirically that what I believed was indeed correct.